# dd command error writing No space left on device

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, redhat

I am new to storage, trying to erase the data in the device `'/dev/sdcd'` why should I get 'No space left error'

```
[root@ dev]# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdcd bs=4k
dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdcd’: No space left on device
1310721+0 records in
1310720+0 records out
5368709120 bytes (5.4 GB) copied, 19.7749 s, 271 MB/s
[root@ dev]# ls -l /dev/null
crw-rw-rw-. 1 root root 1, 3 Oct 27 01:35 /dev/null
```

if this is very basic question,  I am sorry about that

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The `/dev/zero` device will continue to provide zeros for as long as you read from it, all the way to the heat death of the universe should your hardware last that long<sup>(a)</sup>.

With your command, you have no limiting clause like `count=` so it will continue to read from `/dev/zero` and write to `/dev/sdcd`  until the latter runs out of space.

It will still be writing to the device so you can safely ignore the error at the end (although it may be a good idea to ensure the disk is actually an integral multiple of the block size to avoid the possibility of leaving sensitive information at the end).

---

<sup>(a)</sup> It may slow down somewhat in the final stages, as it becomes harder to get useful work out of a universe that's losing all its energy gradients :-)

Comment: This is nice explanation!

Comment: still dont get it though.  I am willing to wipe the entir epartition, in fact it was like that before i ran fdisk to thrown a dos mbr on there, and still, i cant copy /sda1 to the non existent /sdb1, says out of space, after 2 seconds.  What do i need to do to PREPARE SDB for copying partition 1? `if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4k conv=noerror,sync`